# How to exclude 1 item in a list from for...in... loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function to infect and cure a city, except I always want city[0] to remain as infected. all the cities are part of a list.

```
def sim_step(cities , p_spread , p_cure):
    for city in cities:
        if city[1] == True and numpy.random.rand() < p_spread:
            zombify(my_world , cities[numpy.random.randint(city[3])])
        if city[1] == False and numpy.random.rand() < p_cure:
            cure(my_world , cities[numpy.random.randint(city[3])])
```

Comment: What is your problem? please give more infomration about the question and the code iteself

Comment: Hi JBarnes, welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like that:

```py
def sim_step(cities , p_spread , p_cure):
    for city in cities[1:]:
        if city[1] == True and numpy.random.rand() < p_spread:
            zombify(my_world , cities[numpy.random.randint(city[3])])
        if city[1] == False and numpy.random.rand() < p_cure:
            cure(my_world , cities[numpy.random.randint(city[3])])
```

The difference is here: `cities[1:]`. This is called slice operation. To understand more about it read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/788833).

Answer (score 0):

Its too hard to understand with those kind of naming methods.

However , from what i understand, your problem is to collect always the first element while running through your cities list.

I recommend using **enumerate** methods so you can run through both **index of an element**, **the element itself**

Enumerate methods allows to run through list of indexes and the list elements.

```
def sim_step(cities , p_spread , p_cure):
    for index,city in enumerate(cities):
        if city[1] == True and numpy.random.rand() < p_spread:

            zombify(my_world , cities[numpy.random.randint(city[3])])

        if city[1] == False and numpy.random.rand() < p_cure:
            cure(my_world , cities[numpy.random.randint(city[3])])

        if index == 0:
            remain_infected()
```

See here more about the enumerate method:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you just have to make sure that you won't cure the first city (cities[0]).

```
    ...
    if city[1] == False and numpy.random.rand() < p_cure:
        idx = numpy.random.randint(city[3])
        if idx == 0:
            continue
        cure(my_world , cities[idx])
```